What are some mathematical implications or consequences of verifying/proving that there exists a "smallest unit of matter" in our universe?
Aside from the practicality of resolving such a dilemma the likes of "How can you verify that [this] is the smallest possible unit of matter, and no smaller unit of matter can exist?", I'm curious about:

How might such a revelation affect mathematical axioms and other foundational aspects of mathematics (as they exist today)?

Would (some) irrational figures suddenly possess properties of cardinality?



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's not really a math question because it pertains to matter. I don't see how a lower bound would imply anything new mathematically or in relation to cardinality either so it would probably have to be some other properties required to motivate new directions.

Not only would there be no change in existing mathematical structures, there would be no change in macroscopic physics. We already have knowledge of the molecular nature of fluids that contradicts the classical interpretation of Bernoulli's equation, yet we still use that interpretation.

There are none. Mathematics is the study of things that must be true in all possible worlds.
We're already accustomed to the idea that there's no such thing as a perfect circle in real life. Knowing more about the degree to which this is true doesn't change the fact that a hypothetical, mathematically pure perfect circle of radius $r$ would have area $\pi r^2$. (If something physically real deviates from a circle by at most some known amount then its area would deviate from $\pi r^2$ by some known amount.)
The one thing that might happen is, if we discover new physics, we may develop new fields of math in order to help solve problems that arise in that physics. But we wouldn't revise old theorems.
